# URL Rewrite Exclude specific URLs

Tags: php, url, web-config

I know this is probably a simple question but I would like to exclude a file from my URL rewrite rules. Below is the rewrite section of my web.config file (The code was supplied by someone else). I would like to exclude a file called demo-download.php from having it's extension removed. (It is causing issues with some php code I have which uses $_POST).

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\.php$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" negate="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add this line:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern=".*demo\-download\.php" negate="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change both rules.
It would go as follow:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^demo-download" negate="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.php$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
      <match url="^demo-download.php$" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The first rule only applies if the requested file name doesn't start with `demo-download` and has the `.php` extension. The second one applies only if the requested path is not exactly `demo-download.php`